# Custom UI Amazon Lex Bot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I'm developing a Bot to integrate in website using Amazon Lex, I have downloaded the source code of github /aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui but nowhere can I change the UI to adapt it to the design of the website.

Any suggestion to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui/tree/master/src)

> The sample pages available from the test server include index.html and parent.html which demonstrate how to load the chatbot UI component as a full page or as an iframe respectively.

Referenced pages: [index.html](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui/blob/master/src/website/index.html) [parent.html](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui/blob/master/src/website/parent.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can include a file custom-chatbot-style.css from "aws-lex-web-ui/dist", download it, add it to your page or project and make changes.

This way you can change the style of the current component.

Refer this link:- https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/20c56f9e-9c0a-4174-a661-9f40d9f063ac/en-US/web/theming

you can find custom-chatbot-style.css here

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui/blob/master/dist/custom-chatbot-style.css